# A word for "colloquially"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

There's a word (that I can't quick remember) that means `colloquial` / `personal` fits perfectly in this context:

> I haven't conducted any formal studies on the matter, just speaking from _______ experience

The meaning I'm after is "informal" or "personal"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps *anecdotal* is better than colloquial; a formal study can be conduced in informal or colloquial language.  Anecdotes based on whatever the context may consider "formal" English does not necessarily result in a formal study.

Comment: My first reaction to this was that you can't possibly use the phrase "anecdotal experience" because anecdotes are other people's stories, not one's own experiences. But Ngrams shows it is rare but very much on the increase, even in some fairly high-register works.

Comment: @Phil Sweet Thanks for this point--"a collection of anecdotes" would be better than "anecdotal experience"; I guess forcing a word into a sentence on a SWR leads to not saying things quite the way one should, whatever justification Ngram provides.